# What do the blue and green outlines mean when using showsPhysics in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, physics

I'm using showsPhysics in Xcode (swift) and it's really useful, but some of my physics bodies are outlined in blue and some are outlined in green.  What's the difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Volume-based physics bodies are outlined in blue, and Edge-based bodies are green.